# Передача пользовательских объектов WCF-службе

Tags: c#, wcf

Здравствуйте! Как правильно передавать пользовательский объект в качестве параметра в метод OperationContract WCF-службы? Пример кода:

```
 public class MyClass
{
    public int id;
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://C_M_Service")]
    public interface ICMInterface
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/GetCars")]        
        [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

        string GetCars(MyClass data);
    }

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]    
    public class Car_market : ICMInterface
    {

        public string GetCars(MyClass data)
        {

            return("OK: id="+data.id.ToString());            
        }
    }
```

**Обновление**

Выдаётся сообщение о нулевой ссылке на объект. Наверное, надо как-то создать объект, но как не понимаю.

Да, про создание через new - это понятно. Но где его использовать? У меня передаются данные из запроса `JQuery.soap` в `OperationContract` WCF-службы. Когда я в OperationContract WCF-службы в качестве параметра использую, скажем, int всё нормально. Если использовать пользовательский класс - появляется данный вопрос.

Пробовал использовать DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Cars_Data
    {

        [DataMember]
        public int id;
    }
```

Результат: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр".

Код JQuery.soap:

```
$.soap({
            url: "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/",
            method: "GetCars",
            SOAPAction: "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/GetCars",            
            soap11:true,
            data: '<GetCars xmlns="http://C_M_Service"><data xmlns="http://C_M_Service"><id>123</id></data></GetCars>',
            error: function (soapresponse) {
                alert("Error: "+soapresponse.toString());
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert("OK: "+result.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: А именно что не получается?

Comment: Смотрели это: [How to: Create a Basic Data Contract for a Class or Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Хм. Просто при помощи `new`? Покажите код.

Comment: Добавил код в вопросе.

Comment: А что на вызывающей стороне? Где код, который вызывает `GetCars`?

Comment: Добавил в вопросе.

Comment: А, у вас с «той стороны» не C#!.. Хм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передаваемый класс нужно пометить как [контракт данных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms733811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), используя аттрибуты `[DataContract]`/`[DataMember]`:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id;
}
```

также стоит проверить имена и неймспейсы передаваемых элементов. в качестве образца можно использовать запрос из WCF Test Client:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/GetCars</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetCars xmlns="http://C_M_Service">
      <data xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:id>1</d4p1:id>
      </data>
    </GetCars>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

неймспейс для id должен совпадать с `targetNamespace` из `wsdl`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1">
  <xs:complexType name="MyClass">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="MyClass" nillable="true" type="tns:MyClass"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Уже пробовал. Получаю "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр". Класс добавил в вопросе.

Comment: запишите реальный запрос со стороны клиента (fiddler-ом, например) и сравните его с примером, показываемым на странице семплов для вашего сервиса. скорее всего вы где-то не угадали с именем элемента или с неймспейсом, и вам на сервер приходит `data == null`

Comment: Когда тип параметра в OperationContract был int - данные передавались.

Comment: @AN90 так может вы *не угадали с именем элемента* для MyClass? проверьте формат запроса.

Comment: У меня не совпадали имена параметров (было другое имя в SOAP-сообщении). Поменял. Теперь выдаётся "Форматтер сгенерировал исключение при попытке десериализовать сообщение: Ошибка десериализации параметра http://C_M_Service:data. Сообщение InnerException было "Ошибка в строке 1, позиция 264. Ожидается состояние "Element".. Обнаружен "Text" с именем "", пространство имен "". ".  Подробнее см. InnerException"

Comment: @AN90 ну вот теперь у вас точно не совпадает формат параметра - содержимого `<C_M_Service:data>` вместо элемента внутри него приходит текст.

Comment: Я не указал тэг <id> в сообщении. Теперь данные доходят, но ответ в JQuery.soap выдаёт id=0, хотя я посылаю не это значение.

Comment: @AN90 значит до сервера не доходит значение id. значит у вас все-еще ошибка с форматом. или с неймспейсом у элемента id.

Comment: Передаётся так: <GetCars xmlns="http://C_M_Service"><data xmlns="http://C_M_Service"><id>123</id></data></GetCars>.

Comment: @AN90 у id должен быть другой нейсмпейс. Запустите WCF Test Client, посмотрите какой именно. Скорее всего вида `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1`, где `WcfService1` - неймспейс сервиса

Comment: Клиент послал следующее: "<GetCars xmlns="http://C_M_Service">
      <data xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/C_M_Service" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:id>123</d4p1:id>
      </data>
    </GetCars>"

Comment: Исправленное сообщение нормально отправляется, и ответ получается правильным. Большое спасибо!